# Performance issue with React 16.8.5 with large amount of dataset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, setstate

I have a table, and its cells are selectable(Using [react-selectable-fast](https://github.com/valerybugakov/react-selectable-fast)). There are 15000 rows and each row has 30 Selectable cells.
I am having a strange issue with re-rendering.
It's taking longer to re-render the component.

Here is the code sandbox link for the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-vaughan-vnox7

The problem is, when I remove the `setState` method then it works as expected, as there is no re-rendering. But, since the event on a cell needs to be captured in the parent component to make changes in the other form of the page(not available in the code sandbox), so I need to update the state of the component, then the page is taking longer than usual to show the selected cells.

The glitch can be seen here: https://vnox7.csb.app/

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> React designed to be fast but can become very slow.

Why?

Issue #1 - using function components anywhere.

Problem with function component is that it rendering each time when parent renders. So, if you have some heavy calculations inside the functional component (and you have), you will struggle. Even if the DOM will not be updated after recalculation (because of the shadow DOM check), you still need to calculate everything for the comparison.

Take a look here:

```js
const getRows = number => { 
   *heavy calculation*
}
```

And here:

```
 <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>{getHead()}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{getRows(1500)}</tbody>
      </table>
```

Each render you do the same calculations, you actually don't need.

**How to fix:** - change your functional component to the pure component. (Or use react.memo on the functional component)

Issue #2 - allocating garbage (excuse me for such strong word, but this is true)

```js
onSelectionFinish={selected => {
        console.time("EEEE");
        console.log("Selection Started");
        onSelect(selected);
      }}
      ignoreList={[".name-col", ".h-col", ".s-col", ".u-col", ".v-col"]}
```

Here, on each renders you create a new array and new handler. This will increase memory usage and garbage collector work. Usually, this is not an issue but if your component renders often this will become a problem. Or, if you allocate a large amounts of objects like you do in getRows(). It worth mention, that collecting the garbage will completely stop your application.

**How to fix:** -  precalculate everything you can and use the results instead of on-fly calculations. This will save lots of CPU time for you.

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**
As @YashJoshi mentioned,

> windowing technique may help here greatly

To get more info, please check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#virtualize-long-lists)

Comment: Hey Drag13 some really great points and I agree with all the above points. I just wanted to add one point that the `windowing` technique may help here greatly.

Comment: Thanks! @Drag13, for the suggested points, will give it a go. And Thank Yash for the suggestions. Will accept if things work for me.

Comment: @SonuBamniya does this help?

Comment: @Drag13 Yes it did.

Comment: I was digging into this more and I achieved this without using react-window. This will only re-render the updated element. Let me know, what do you think of this. Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/performance-issue-yemug . @Drag13 if you can also add your thoughts it would be great.

Comment: @YashJoshi the example you created is crashing the system. btw, I was able to achieve the desired result with `react-virtualized`. Thank you for your support. Marking this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Drag13  @YashJoshi,

I totally agree that [windowing](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) will help here, but also we should consider that change of cell should not re-render the whole table (current window) or any other component on the page

@SonuBamniya instead of using parent component to capture the state you should consider using React Context / redux / any other state management library which captures the cell change. Also, divide each cell into an individual component that updates context and then you can use that context in your form component instead of the whole parent component.

This will reduce re-renders drastically.

Comment: Thanks! @lakhansamani, working with `GraphQL`, so already using apollo store.